# laravel voyager panel multi language error

Tags: laravel, voyager

I was trying to develop a multilingual website project using laravelde voyager panel, but the Undefined array key "en" error I got causes a problem. To elaborate, I opened the multi-language option and added the en and tr options, I created a table, then I created the breadini with the model, I entered the content for the tr and en options but I get this error while recording or updating when I am in the en option. Is there anyone who can provide a solution to this? I don't think there is a problem in my work. I think there is a problem with the library.

`[[error and codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFvHh.png)e description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WevqW.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CypLV.png)`

I tried to fix the error by changing laravel vite voyager versions but it didn't work